# How to move only the first file from a folder if this folder contains more than 100 files?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to build a script that moves the first file (ordered by name) if the source folder contains more than 100 files in it.

I got here but it moves all the files instead of only one.

Can someone help me please?

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d C:\SOURCE ^|find /c /v ""') do set "remaining=%%a" 

forfiles /P C:\SOURCE /M * /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE if %remaining% geq 100 move @FILE "C:\TARGET""
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need `forfiles` (by the way: you explicitly tell it to move all files (`/m *`):

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /d "C:\SOURCE"
set num=0  
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /o-n * ^|findstr /n "^"') do set /a "num=%%a" & set "file=%%b"
echo debug: %num% files. To move: %file%
if %num% gtr 100 move "%file%" "c:\target\"
```